# Sample ruby program keeps running with errors, can't figure them out

Tags: ruby, rubygems, syntax-error

Alright, I have tried my best to get this code to just run without spitting out errors, but to no avail. Hopefully you can help me out.

```
require 'launchy'

#def linebreak(breakline)

def program()
    puts "Welcome to test program v1. Would you like to continue? ENTER y for Yes or n for no"
    user_input_1 = gets.chomp

    if user_input_1 == "y"
        puts "How would you like to proceed CRASH | TEXTMAKER | UNDECIDED // CASE SENSITIVE"
        user_input_2 = gets.chomp

        if user_input_2 == "CRASH"
            while true Launchy.open("http://google.com")
        elsif user_input_2 = "TEXTMAKER"
            while true out_file.puts("test program v1")
        else
            puts "You have not entered a method."
        elsif user_input_1 == "n"
            abort
        else
            puts "That is not a valid command. Please run the script again."
        end
    end
```

Comment: Please don't make us guess. Edit your question to include the actual error messages you're getting including the line number and backtrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright there's a few problems, but don't worry everything can be
fixed!

Let's start with **what you did well**

- Good job using your booleans in most cases, most beginners don't seem
  to grasp that `==` means equal, and `=` means something    completely
  different
- Good job with the `puts` and using it properly, there are other
  methods which I will cover later, that will look much better in your 
  case.

Now let's cover **what can be fixed**

- As I stated above in most cases you used your Boolean correctly
  however you seem to have missed one. `elsif user_input_2 = "TEXTMAKER"` you need a `==` to show that it is equal.
- Your `while` loop doesn't seem to make any sense because you don't ever really set anything as `true`. In Ruby it is highly
  recommended to never use a `while` loop, of course there are times
  that you have to, but only after you've tried everything else.
- `elsif; else; elsif` **never** use an `elsif` after an `else`. `elsif` is to provide an exception, in your case there's more then
  one option so use the `elsif`s before the else, you'd be better using a case statement here.
- Not to sound like an ass, but your indentation is horrible. You'd find a lot more problems with good indentation, in Ruby that's two
  spaces, here's the style guide:
  https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide
- Never have your users options be case sensitive, if somebody else is going to use your program, just assume they are the dumbest people in the world and make it super easy for them. `user_input_2.gets.chomp.upcase` this will set it so that no matter how they enter their text, it will always be upper case.
- You're missing an `end` this will become clear once you've used proper indentation

Alright let's rewrite this thing:

```
require 'launchy'

def program #<= you don't need the parentheses
  print "Welcome to the test program version 1, to continue type 'c' to exit type 'e': "
  user_input = gets.chomp.upcase
  if user_input == "C"
    program_choices
  elsif user_input == "E"
    puts "Exiting.."
    exit
    #if you really want to use abort
    #abort("Exiting..") 
    #you won't need to use exit if you use abort
  else 
    puts "Invalid input, try again"
    program #<= this is a loop known as recursion, don't use it to much
  end
end

def program_choices
  print "Pick an option, the choices include CRASH | TEXTMAKER | UNDECIDED: "
  user_input = gets.chomp.upcase
  case user_input #<= this is how you start a case statement
  when "CRASH"
    Launchy.open("http://google.com")
  when "TEXTMAKER"
    write_test_data
  when "UNDECIDED"
    puts "You really need to make up your mind.." #<= have some fun with it, that's the point of programming.
    program_choices
  else
    puts "Invalid input, try again"
    program_choices
  end
end

def write_test_data
  x = "Test file version 1"
  if File.exist?("path/to/test/file.txt")
    File.open("path/to/test/file.txt", "a"){ |s| s.write(x) }
  else 
    new_test_file = File.new("path/to/test/file.txt")
    new_test_file.puts(x)
  end
end
```

And bam! Your program is up and running! If you have any questions about anything don't hesitate to ask, programming can be very tricky, and it can be very hard. Keep it up and you'll get there!

Answer (score -1):

I see plenty of problems.

1. This isn't valid:

   ```
   while true Launchy.open("http://google.com")
   ```

   Neither is this:

   ```
   while true out_file.puts("test program v1")
   ```

   I can't tell you how to fix this, though, since it's not at all clear what you're trying to do.
2. An `if` block may only have one `else`, and it must come after all `elsif`s.
3. Here:

   ```
   elsif user_input_2 = "TEXTMAKER"
   ```

   You're assigning a new value to `user_input_2`. I'm guessing you meant to use the equality operator, which is `==`.
4. Your `def` block doesn't have an `end`. This became obvious after I edited your code to use proper indentation. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble by using sensible indentation and whitespace.